# Meteor - Checking login status before rending templates

Tags: javascript, meteor

New to meteor and attempting to check if the user is logged in before rendering templates. I was able to create this functionality with the code below, however it requires a browser page refresh and is not automatically updating on the page.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
 mustBeSignedIn();
}

function mustBeSignedIn() {
 if (Meteor.userId() == null) {
  console.log('Not logged in');
}
  else {
    loadTemplate_tableview()
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated on the best way to approach this without the need for page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that directly in the template.

```html
<template name="templateName">
    {{#if currentUser}}
        <p>You're logged in!</p>
    {{else}}
        <p>You're not logged in.</p>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

For more information about the `currentUser` helper, see http://docs.meteor.com/#template_currentuser

Comment: Thanks brother! Exactly what I needed, the currentUser helper works like a charm.